# Как регуляркой заменить слово, содержащее букву?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Решил увеличить релевантность поиска. Есть поисковый запрос "елка" и "ёлка". Результатов поиска тоже два. Хотелось бы показывать оба результата поиска по обоим запросам.

Единственное, на что у меня хватило знаний - это заменить елка на `ё|елка`, но **мне нужно получить** `ёлка|елка`. Для этой задачи мне нужно с помощью регулярки выбрать слово целиком, в котором содержится буква ё.

```
$query = preg_replace("/(ё|е)/isu" ,"ё|е", $query);
// получаю ё|елка
```

Подскажите, как выбрать слово целиком?

Comment: Какое значение содержится в $query? елка? Попробуйте `$query = preg_replace("/[ёе]/iu" ,"[ЁёЕе]", $query);`

Comment: что-то не понял, вы `e` или `ё` заменяете на строку `ё|e` и из `елка` или `ёлка` получаете, что логично, как и пишите, `e|ёлка`, а хотите то что получить? и почему для поиска просто `ё` на `e` заменить нельзя?

Comment: Мне нужно в поиске не `e|ёлка`, а `елка|ёлка`

Comment: Достаточно заменить все `ё` и `е` на `[ёе]` в шаблоне. Или на `[ЁёЕе]` если нужен регистронезависимый поиск.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Нет, этого недостаточно. Поиск происходит в БД, там механизм другой. Там tsquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что можно так:

```
$query = preg_replace("/(\w*)[ёе](\w*)/isu" ,"$1ё$2|$1е$2", $query);
```

Comment: Да, я был близок к этому, но почему-то не вышло. Это действительно работает, но если в слове стречается несколько `е`, заменяется только одна. Но мне этого достаточно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Написал вот такой код для преобразований:

```
$query = preg_replace_callback("/(\w+)/isu" , function($word) {
    $word = end($word);
    if (preg_match("/(е|ё)/isu", $word)) {
        return preg_replace("/е/isu", "ё", $word) . '|' . preg_replace("/ё/isu", "е", $word);
    }
    return $word;
}, $query);
```

На входе имеем строку `елка тест поиск` на выходе `ёлка|елка тёст|тест поиск`
Если в ответах будет предложено решение с одной регуляркой, с удовольствием отмечу как ответ

Comment: Это надо перенести в вопрос.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Этот является решением вопроса и вполне может быть ответом. Если вы не согласны, можете отметить мой ответ соответствующей тревогой.

Comment: @teran Я написал в вопросе, что получаю и что хочу получить.